# Which is correct: "the picture has been taken from the camera" or "a picture has taken from the camera"?

Tags: passive-voice

Which is correct?

> The picture has been taken from the camera.

or

> A picture has taken from the camera.

I want to know when do we apply passive voice and active voice. I am trying to practice active and passive voices.

Comment: Your question is a bit general.  Have you looked at any [references on how to use the passive voice](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/)?   In your example sentences, "the picture has been taken" is correct, and "the picture has taken" is incorrect, because the second one is not the passive voice, but the present perfect tense.  Passive voice always requires **to be** (like "has been") and a past participle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example in the question's header, these are the most obvious ways to apply the active and passive voices:

*A picture was taken by the camera.*

*The camera took a picture.*

One difference contrasted with your example, of course, is my use of a different preposition, because the one you used is incorrect in that context. My example implies that the camera takes the picture automatically, for example, triggered by motion in its field of view.

When a person is operating a camera, we might say something like:

*That picture was taken by me.*

*I took that picture.*

At this stage in your learning of English, I'd advise you to use active voice as much as possible when one of your main aims is to arouse or maintain your reader's or listener's interest, and reserve use of the passive voice for making reports of events or activities when you can anticipate that your audience merely expects to be informed. However, you can see in my second example that the active voice emphasises your role in the creation of the picture, while the passive voice emphasises that the interest is in the picture itself.

Sometimes, of course, it is simply awkward to force yourself to use active voice, and your audience will appreciate your use of the most appropriate style. I know that doesn't help you to figure out when forcing use of the active voice will become 'awkward'; this is probably something you can only master with experience and having your audience comment on your writing or speaking.